# Generating dataset to fit to LogisticRegression, but not DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, decision-tree

Have a study case, need some help.
I have 2 classifiers, LogisticRegression, and DecisionTreeClassifier with depth 3. Need to generate 3 datasets 1000x2, 500 objects in each class. First dataset should have score > 0.9 with LR and score < 0.7 with Trees, second dataset should do the opposite. Third should have score < 0.7 with both. Overfitting can be ignored for this question.  Any ideas?

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

    clf1 = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',C=1e9) # very weak l2-regularization
    clf2 = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3)

    import numpy as np

    y = np.zeros(1000)
    y[500:] = 1.

   #should change this
    x1 = np.zeros((1000,2))

    x2 = np.zeros((1000,2))


    x3 = np.zeros((1000,2))

    clf_names = ['LogReg', 'DT']
    clfs      = [clf1,     clf2]
    ​
    for dataset in [x1,x2,x3]:
        for i in range(2):
            print (clf_names[i], round(clfs[i].fit(dataset,y).score(dataset,y),3))
    LogReg 0.5
    DT 0.5
    LogReg 0.5
    DT 0.5
    LogReg 0.5
    DT 0.5
```

Comment: You can use [make_classification](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_classification.html) to generate artificial datasets.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as I mentioned, it is a study case and I am only able to change x1, x2, x3 (comment in the code). Othervise it would not be fun =)

Comment: You can set the number of features in make_classification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you approach which might work as per my understanding but can not give you code :D

Main Difference between Logistic Regression and Decision Tree:
1) Logistic regression draws straight line to differentiate 2 classes where Decision Tree can be useful when when it's not possible to differentiate between 2 classes with straight line. You can use decision tree in this scenario as it can give non linear boundary to differentiate between classes.

Approach:
- Try to generate dataset from random module of python and plot it using matplotlib(use 2 different color for classification according to your decision variable Y).
- From plot if you see that it's not possible to differentiate between 2 classes through straight line that Decision tree will perform better than Logistic Regression and vice versa.

It'll be little more difficult to find out scenario where Logistic Regression performs better than Decision Tree.

Both will perform worst when data is spread out randomly and it's not possible to separate it through straight line/polynomial degree curve as well.

.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it.

Comment: Use numpy.random module and always use seed/randomstate when generating dataset that way you'll be able to reproduce results.But it was interesting question.Also plot dataset always that way you'll be able to get more insight into data and looking at plot you'll be able to tell which classification algorithm will work better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0,1,2000)
x1[1000:] = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
x1[1500:] = np.linspace(0,1,500)
x1 = x1.reshape((1000,2))

x2 = np.ones((2000, 1))
x2[500:] = np.full((1500,1), -3)
x2[1000:] = np.full((1000,1), -1)
x2 = x2.reshape(1000,2)

x3 = np.random.randint(0,100,2000).reshape(1000,2)
```

Gives:

```
LogReg 1.0
DT 0.627
LogReg 0.5
DT 1.0
LogReg 0.518
DT 0.555
```